# How to animate videoView along with the imageView and recyclerView?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I want to use animate on videoView which is above the imageView and recyclerView. At first, videoView's visibility is Gone and when i click on the item on the recyclerView i want to make videoView Visible with the animation sliding down and also use animation to the imageView to slideUp and make it Gone. How can i do that. I have given the snapshot of before and after of the layout.

Before Animation:

[image: Before Animation]

After Animation:

[image: After Animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done for a similar situation. In your layout you need to put both views one above the other (on the exact places where they have to appear). Add the global layout listener to the videoView / imageView once in onCreate and then just change the visibility of the according view. This code could be reused with the imageView, but keep in mind that you cannot change the visibility of both views at the same time, because they will overlap. Maybe you need to wait for the first animation to go off and then show the next. It's up to you.

```
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 350;

private void addVideoViewAnimation(final View videoView) {
    videoView.setTag(videoView.getVisibility());
    videoView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int newVisibility = videoView.getVisibility();
            if ((int) videoView.getTag() != newVisibility) {
                videoView.setTag(newVisibility);

                TranslateAnimation animation;
                if (newVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -videoView.getHeight(), 0);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                } else {
                    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -videoView.getHeight());
                    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                }
                animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
                videoView.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }
    });
}
```